vscode debugger highlights wrong line when adding/removing previous lines
Let's assume we have this python script, set breakpoint on second line and start debugging:
print(1)
print(2)  # set breakpoint here
print(3)
print(4)
print(5)

Debugger stops here:

Now delete the first line, the editor looks like this:

And press your key for "Step Over". The highlighted line now should be print(3), but instead the highlighting jumps to third line (print(4)):

After stepping over the current line, the number "3" is printed (which is correct) and not highlighted "4".
Can we somehow fix the highlighted line when adding/removing (lines during debugging) before currently executed line?
